# React State not updating before the rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-state

I'm just wondering why the state is not updating before the rendering?

I am creating a movie listing app & right now I am trying to list the box office movies. but the state doesn't seem to update before the rendering.

I am new to react and js I'd really appreciate some help and explanation of why this is happening

````
const BoxOffice = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getBoxOffices = async () => {
    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com/",
      params: { type: "get-boxoffice-movies", page: "1" },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "4ccc11616emsha0ff93487313f1ep1528a9jsnf24cc1750061",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.movie_results);
        const boxOfficeMovies = response.data.movie_results;
        setData(boxOfficeMovies);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const getfullData = async () => {
    getBoxOffices();
    console.log("data", data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getfullData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="min-h-screen w-screen bg-gray-300 pt-12">
        <div className="min-w-auto grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-5 gap-4 items-center justify-center mt-5">
          <div className="w-screen bg-red-50">
            {data && <Card data={data} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BoxOffice;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal flow of React's component mounting. Just as in class based components, after constructor(), `render` is executed, then componentDidMount and then other life-cycle methods. In the same way, in function components the jsx returning is treated as render and hence it runs before any other life-cycle method which in this case is  `useEffect()`, so this hook will run afterwards, whether it is being used as didMount or didUpdate.
Also do remember setState() and its alternate methods are asynchronous, they don't execute immediately i.e don't have blocking nature. Hence there is a need of such methods which can hint us as soon as state is changed.